# JQuery - ToggleClass/AddClass/RemoveClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following codes to create a top sliding admin panel, that will appear from the very top of the page. This sliding panel will be activated but clicking on the button "#tp-button2".

However, I would like to add one more sliding panel and call it #toppanel2.

**Behavior**

tp-button2: when click, it will either show or hide toppanel, and if toppanel2 is "show", to slide it back into position before it slides out toppanel

tp-button3: same behavior as above but for toppanel2

**Current Situation**: I'm using toggleClass which is easy for just 1 panel since it's to turn and off, but I'm not sure the algorithem to achieve the above, and i've tried long methods including addClass and removeClass and it's not working out because removeClass doesn't work.

**This is what i'm using for single toggleClass**

**Original CSS**

```
#tp-button2,tp-button3 {
}
.toppanel {
height: 150px ;
top:-150px; 
background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
position: '.$dimensionposition.' !important;
}
.toppanel2 {
height: 75px ;
top:-75px;
background-color: #F1F1F1 !important;
position: absolute !important;
}

.show {top:0px}
.tp-relative {position: relative;padding-bottom: 150px;}
.tp-relative2 {position: relative;padding-bottom: 75px;}
</style>
```

**Original Javascript**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {
    $j( "#tp-button" ).click(function(){
    $j(".toppanel").toggleClass("show", 900, "easeOutBounce");
    $j("#tp-relativeblock").toggleClass("tp-relative", 900, "easeOutBounce");
    });
});
</script>
```

**I've attempted something like this**

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();


$j(function() {


$j("body").on("click", "#tp-button2", function(){

    if ($j("#toppanel").hasClass("show")) {
    alert("tp-button2 remove class");
    $j("#toppanel").removeClass("show", 900);
    $j("#tp-relativeblock").removeClass("tp-relative", 900);
} else {
    alert("tp-button2 addClass");
    $j("#toppanel2").removeClass("show", 900).delay(900).queue($j("#tp-relativeblock").addClass("tp-relative", 900));

    $j("#tp-relativeblock").removeClass("tp-relative2", 900).delay(900).queue($j("#toppanel").addClass("show", 900));

}

});


$j("body").on("click", "#tp-button3", function(){
if ($j("#toppanel2").hasClass("show")) {
    alert("tp-button3 removeClass");
    $j("#toppanel2").removeClass("show", 900);
    $j("#tp-relativeblock").removeClass("tp-relative2", 900);

} else {
    // Here i attempt to just bring down panel 2 without closing panel 1 to see whether there's code above that's wrong but it's not working too.
    alert("tp-button3 addClass");
    $j("#tp-relativeblock").addClass("tp-relative2", 900);
    $j("#toppanel2").addClass("show", 900)

}

});
```

**This is what i have on body**

```
<div id="tp-button"><i class="'.$iconstop.'"></i></div>
<div id="toppanel" class="toppanel">
<div id="tp-container">
<div class="tp-s1">
THIS IS PANEL 1 COLUMN 1
</div>
<div class="tp-s2">
THIS IS PANEL 1 COLUMN 2
</div>
<div class="tp-s3">
THIS IS PANEL 1 COLUMN 3
</div>
<div class="tp-s4">
THIS IS PANEL 1 COLUMN 3        
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="toppanel2" class="toppanel2">
<div id="tp-container">
<div class="tp-s1">
PANEL 2
</div>
<div class="tp-s2">
PANEL 2
</div>
<div class="tp-s3">
PANEL 2
</div>
<div class="tp-s4">
PANEL 2
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="tp-relativeblock"></div>
```

I understand addClass and removeClass and what it does but sometimes removeClass doesn't remove tp-relative from tp-relativeblock so it doesn't move back up to space.
Click Button2:

toppanel slide down **Success**

relativeblock slidedown **Success**

Second Button 2 Click:

toppanel slides up to 0px **Success**

remove tp-relative from #tp-relativeblock **failed**

Click button3:

Nothing Happens

Button2 also became disabled

Amature here to javascript and jquery, so will appreciate all help i can to achieve this.

My objective is for panel 1 to show "Login TO Website" and panel 2 to show "Register To Website"

**THANK YOU IN ADVANCED!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the jQuery I use to add and remove classes

To add:

```
$("#some-id").toggleClass('class-name', 'add');
```

To Remove:

```
$("#some-id").toggleClass('class-name', 'remove');
```

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/benPearce/t6bQb/2) toggleClass is used to trigger css animations

Comment: does this work on jquery-ui because jquery-ui is what im using, how do i add the timeduration and animation then?

Comment: You can chain jQuery events onto the single id

Comment: please guide me along, i'm not too sure what u mean, i use removeClass and addClass because it has the animation

Comment: @DaveTeu check out this fiddle it uses toggleClass in conjunction with CSS animations http://jsfiddle.net/benPearce/t6bQb/2/